# Array to String conversion error when rendering a template

Tags: symfony

I'm setting up a new web application project and ran the commands to generate a user class and CRUD templates (https://symfony.com/blog/new-and-improved-generators-for-makerbundle).

When I go to the user index page it loads accordingly, however when I try to go to user/new I get an Array to string conversion exception.

If I comment out the generated {{ include('user/_form.html.twig') }} in new.html.twig the page loads. So I've been focusing on the form that is getting passed to _form.html.twig.

I suspect the issue is with the User attribute Roles which is array, but I'm not certain.

This is all Symfony generated code - I've not modified or written anything here.

This is where the error is being thrown:

UserController.php

```
return $this->render('user/new.html.twig', [
'user' => $user,
'form' => $form->createView(),]);
```

_form.html.twig

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
  {{ form_widget(form) }}
  <button class="btn">{{ button_label|default('Save') }}</button>
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

User class attributes

```
class User implements UserInterface
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=180, unique=true)
     */
    private $username;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="json")
     */
    private $roles = [];

    /**
     * @var string The hashed password
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $password;
```

From what I understand Symfony will try to guess the field types and construct the form accordingly. So I'm not sure if it's the array field type that is causing this or if it's actually coming from the createView call.

Added UserType.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\User;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class UserType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('username')
            ->add('roles')
            ->add('password')
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => User::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, could you paste form class code (UserType?)? Thanks

Comment: @IgorW. I see now that the make:crud generates a UserType class as well. I've updated the question with that code. Thank you.

Comment: I think you should create a  choice select for attr roles
https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html

Comment: @hous that is what it was, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

yes, the bug is in the role property (array). You have to specify the type in your form -> [CollectionType](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html). There are possibility to use allow_add to add new items to collection and allow_delete to delete items from collection. You can specify entry_options to specify, how data in collection are load - choice label and other... (everything is in [docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html#entry-options)). Your controller is OK. After this adjustment the form is load.

UserType.php

```
$builder
        ->add('email', EmailType::class)
        ->add('roles', CollectionType::class, [
            'entry_type' => TextType::class,
        ])
        ->add('isVerified')
        ->add('save', SubmitType::class)
    ;
```

_form.html.twig

```
{% block content %}
    <h1>users</h1>
    {{ form_start(form) }}
        {{ form_row(form.email) }}
        {{ form_label(form.roles) }}
        {{ form_errors(form.roles) }}
            <ul>
                {% for role in form.roles %}
                    <li>
                        {{ form_errors(role) }}
                         {{ form_widget(role) }}
                    </li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        {{ form_row(form.isVerified) }}
    {{ form_end(form) }}
{% endblock %}
```